# How to filter mongodb documents by array of objects

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query, aggregate

I have an array like the following structure
`[{"id":1,"address":"UK"},{"id":2,"address":"US"}]`

I want to fetch all entries from mongodb where id = 1 and address = "UK" OR  id = 2 and address = "US"

Comment: Use `$elemMatch`

Comment: Is this array a entry in the collection or is it a value of a particular key in the document?

Comment: This is in entire collection . You can assume that collection structure is exactly like the array which we sent and we need some of the elements

Answer (score 0):

let's assume your collection is `test_collection`, this could do the work.

It works well in `DataGrip`, you may try it in your mongodb client.

```
const arr = [{"id":1,"address":"UK"},{"id":2,"address":"US"},{"id":2,"address":"CN"}];
arr.forEach((v) => {
    db.test_collection.find({id: v.id, address: v.address}).forEach(
            function (order) {
                let row = {}
                row.id = order.id;
                row.address = order.address;
    //            row.other_field = order.other_field;
                print(row);
    });
})
;
```